# method name expected/no overload matches delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, eventtrigger, eventargs, missingmethodexception

I have this button with the following code

```
newEnterPass pass = new newEnterPass();
private void truncateEmp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //TRUNCATE EMPLOYEES
    {
        if (pass.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pass.proceed.Click += new EventHandler<newEnterPass>(pass.truncateEmp(sender,e));
        }
    }
```

It gives me the error `Method name expected`. If I remove the code `(sender, e)` then it will give me another error

`No overload for 'truncateEmp' matches delegate System.EventHandler<cms.newEnterPass>'`

Here's the code of `truncateEmp` from the class `newEnterPass`

```
public void truncateEmp(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        string pass = passField.Text;
        if (pass == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Did you input something? I doubt it.");
            return;
        }

        bool r = validate_login(pass);
        if (r)
        {
            db_connection();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE Employees";
            cmd.Connection = connect;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Success!", "TRUNCATE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            logs.LogThatShit_TruncateEmp();
            this.Close();
            passField.Clear();

            connect.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong password!", "TRUNCATE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            passField.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Can someone help? Thank you everyone!

Comment: You cannot pass in parameters to the method when constructing the delegate. Try `new EventHandler<newEnterPass>(pass.truncateEmp)` instead.

Comment: Why did you put `newEnterPass` class name as a generic parameter for `EventHandler`?

Comment: Why do you need `<newEnterPass>`? Just mention `+= new EventHandler(pass.truncateEmp);`

Comment: @praty That did the trick. Can you post it as an answer so I can upvote? Thank you!

Comment: Sure. Added as an answer now

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `<newEnterPass>`. Rewrite your event handling as

```
pass.proceed.Click += new EventHandler(pass.truncateEmp);
```

Comment: You say you don't need `<newEnterPass>` but then proceed to include it in your "corrected" code. You should either correct your code to what you think should be used or explain more clearly what you mean. As it is I don't think even removing that will make it work...

Comment: Its probably worth explicitly calling out the more important change which is changing the parameter to EventHandler to the method group rather than an invocation of the method as it was before.